# Applying different images in install.wim during the installation setup

Tags: iso-image, windows-installation, wim

I have images captured of my `C:` & `D:` & I want these two images applied to `C:` & `D:` during installations henceforth. So I was thinking, I would replace the `install.wim` in the `\sources` of a Win 11 installation media with a WIM containing these two images. I haven't tried this but I garner that the setup will only apply the WIM's index 1 to C:, hence the problem.

Now, I happen to remember that multi-edition Windows installation media contain different images. So I `get-imageinfo`-ed the `install.wim` of a multi-edition Windows installation media & found not only two, but eleven images (compactified by multi-referencing the files).

So, is there script in the Windows installation process that's for deciding which edition image to use that I could repurpose to apply one image after another (`C:` & then `D:`)?

Comment: Just to clarify, you have C: and D: running separate versions of windows on the same machine? And you want to capture these drives as an image for deployment to multiple machines with identical hardware config? Is this a dual boot system?

Comment: C: is still the bootable drive that contains Windows. D: contains directories that are traditionally also at C:, but I moved to D: — PerfLogs, ProgramData, Temp, Users.